# How to install Dash Reports on Ubuntu

Tags: tomcat

[Dash Reports](http://www.dashreports.org/) does not provide any installation help. It offers a `.war` for download and that is it. I guess using Apache Tomcat would be a logical thing to do, but what are the steps to get this piece of software to run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install Dash Reports:

- [Download](https://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi) the binary core `tar.gz` of Apache Tomcat 7.0 (Assuming Java 1.6 or higher is installed; This method is easier than using Ubuntu's package management which delivers Tomcat using tight security settings)
- Unpack it somewhere in your `home` folder (I will be using `~/bin/apache-tomcat-7.0.52`)
- [Download](http://www.dashreports.org/download.html) the latest release of Dash Reporter
- Put the `.war` in Tomcat's `webapps` folder (eg, `~/bin/apache-tomcat-7.0.52/webapps/dashreports-1.1.war`
- Start Tomcat from the command line

  - Go to Tomcats's binary folder: `cd ~/bin/apache-tomcat-7.0.52/bin`
  - Start the Tomcat server: `./startup.sh`
- In your browser go to: `http://localhost:8080/dashreports-1.1`
- Log in with the default credentials

  - Username: `admin`
  - Password: `password`

Some basic Dash Reports usage:

- Add your database via `Manage` -> `Datasources` (if you connect to a remote database, make sure your database user is allowed to connect from the machine where Dash Reports is installed)
- Create a chart

  - Go to `My Groups` -> `Example Group` (this is the default; you can create different groups)
  - Select `Chart` from the pull-down menu and click `Add`
  - Type a name and insert your SQL query (it is easiest to create your query in your normal database management program like for example HeidiSQL)
  - An example of an SQL query output useable by `Chart`:

    ```
    | NAME | AGE |
    --------------
    | Mary | 25  |
    | John | 23  |
    | Kate | 27  |
    ```
  - Under the `Layout` tab you can set the size of the chart and once you have multiple charts, grids, etc. you can arrange them using `Display Column` and `Display Row`
  - Under the `Schedule` tab you can set when the query has to be run in order to refresh the chart (default is once every minute)
  - For the chart to work, go to tab `Chart Details` and fill in the `Y-Axis Label`, `X-Axis Column Name` and `Value Column Name`